# how to insert fields from one model to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model with multiple associations:

```
has_many labouritems
has_many materialitems
```

I have another association to quotes called invoice; how do I insert the `labouritems` and material records to invoice but create new instance of them but keep the value? The purpose is to keep a historic record of the values at a point in time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a duplicate of your model instance with `dup`

```
duplicate = labouritems.dup
duplicate.save
```

Comment: so it will be something like,  invoices.labouritems.build ? how do i save to instance model?